# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Multiple Tomcat Instances

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, shared-libraries, solaris-10

We have 2 Tomcat 7 instance installed in a Solaris server. The 2 instances share the same shared lib folder /usr/tomcat7/lib.

A Java class, say SingleSignOn.java calls a native library called lib_sso using following code

```
System.loadLibrary("lib_sso");
```

SingleSignOn.class is in shared lib folder and is used by most web applications contained in both Tomcat instances. Applications in Instance 1 work well. However, applications in Instance 2 do not. An "UnsatisfiedLinkError" is thrown out from SingleSignOn. Any idea how to fix this?